# Riemann sum and integral approximation error (Lipschitz function)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Given a function is Lipschitz continuous on [0,1]

such that ∀ x , y ∈ [0 , 1] , | f(x) - f(y) | ≤ M | x - y | for M ∈ ℝ

how would you prove:

[image]

I tried to use the fact that we can find a point in each sub interval where the difference between the supremum and infimum is less than M/2n and riemann sum using those points

but that does not guarantee the difference is greater than the needed one..

Thanks,

Comment: The link to the image rotted. Fix it ASAP, or the question may go down the tube.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Write the difference as

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \int_{(k-1)/n}^{k/n}(f(x)-f(k/n))\,dx$$

Comment: Can you elaborate please? 
using this and the average value theorem we can get the difference to be f(c) - f(k/n), but why is that less than m/2n necessarily. Or what am I missing?

Comment: Slap absolute values in there and recall the definition of Lipschitz.

Comment: I don't quite see where 1/2 comes in.

Comment: You have lots of hints. Spend some more time on it.

Comment: I see it, that's really cool. thanks a lot